# Recaptcha v3 - low scores for most of the users in 3 apps

Tags: nuxt.js, nestjs, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

The more users started using an endpoint with recapthca, the lower scores they started getting. Most of the values are around 0.1.

[image: Recaptchas scores]

My structure looks like I have a 3 front-end apps and one common server for them. Each of the web app is using same public key.

In all apps I am using (fe): https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/recaptcha
BE: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nestlab/google-recaptcha

I suspect that the problem may be connected to having 3 different web apps for the same key but then it will be problematic to validate it on be.